# Disable screen rotate completely

Tags: windows-8, display-rotation

I have Windows 8 on a notebook. It makes no sense to rotate the screen while working. But it happens from time to time.

How can I completely disable this feature. I don't want to switch on/off this feature, I simple don't want it in any case (unwanted keyboard hits).

Comment: If you disabled it then it won't happen why are you against that solution?  Your unlikely going to be able to remove the feature because the feature is supported by the drivers you have installed.

Comment: If you mean disable with W-O, noob users will switch it on again with unwanted key hit. And I cannot find it in the graphics card settings ...

Comment: The instruction would depend if we are talking about Nvidia or AMD.